# How to install sap business one client

Tags: windows-7, accounting

Please help, I need to install this software but there are some prerequisites that needs to be installed before I can install it.
Problem is, I can't find download links for those. And it seems that they are not free software.
Even the software itself is not free. Can you provide me with some open-source alternatives for this software. Or if you have used it before, how did you install it.

Comment: Please give specifics. This question as it stands is too vague to be of any use.

Answer (score 1):

When running the main installation you will be asked whether you want to install the server components, the client components or both. I have not seen the client components available seperately.

Prerequisites to a successful client install generally require the server components to already be installed and the license server services to be running.

All the documentation is on the SAP Business One Customer Portal. You are given log in credentials when you purchase Business One.

I'm not aware of any open-source equivalents to SAP Business One.

Comment: I'm only relying on torrents for this one since I don't have the money to buy the actual software because I'm only a student.